# Include all references from another project in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# application that does all kinds of automation stuff based on voice commands.

I want other users to be able to develop plugins that can add additional functionality.

If the users create a new project for a plugin, is there a way to have it reference all the dlls that the main application references?

Comment: Would you supply the DLLs for developers to use / attach to their Plug-ins?  I assume they are probably not essential for all plug-in development, but you want them included in any plug-ins...

Comment: Creating a project template is dead-simple, File + Export Template.  Getting it deployed to the user's machine with a VSIX package is a bigger hassle, start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx).